# HTML svg animation issues

Tags: jquery, html, animation, svg

I am trying to create simple animation with SVG and HTML only.
The goal is:

1. Take the first picture and move it from position (80,100) to (100,100)
2. Take the second picture and move it from position (80,100) to (95,100)
3. Take the third picture and move it from position (80,100) to (90,100)
4. Hide all three pictures
5. Repeat steps 1-4

I have something like this :

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
   <image xlink:href="pic.png" height="30" width="30"/>
    <path id="path1" d="M 80 100 l 20 0" />
    <animateMotion dur="1" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="0" >
       <mpath xlink:href="#path1"/>
    </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

In this case, first picture moved from (80,100) to (100,100) but as soon as it reached the final position it started moving again from (80,100).

How can I make every following picture 'wait' for all the rest pics and then start moving first picture from (80,100) again?

Comment: If step 4 hides everything step 5 is pointless isn't it, you'll just move hidden things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what step 4 is about since it means step 5 will move invisible items but you make animations wait by setting their begin to the previous animations end event like so...

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
        <path id="path1" d="M 0 0 l 20 0"/>
    </defs>
    <rect width="50" height="50" fill="blue">
      <animateMotion id="motion1" begin="0s;motion2.end" dur="1" rotate="0" fill="freeze">
         <mpath xlink:href="#path1"/>
      </animateMotion>
    </rect>
    <rect y="80" width="50" height="50" fill="blue">
      <animateMotion id="motion2" begin="motion1.end" dur="1" rotate="0" fill="freeze">
         <mpath xlink:href="#path1"/>
      </animateMotion>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are just moving in a straight line, you don't need to use `<animateMotion>`. You can just animate the `x` and `y` attributes.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 150 150">

   <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-30-30-1.jpg" height="30" width="30" x="80" y="100">
     <animate id="one" attributeName="x" begin="0s;three.end+2s" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
              from="80" to="100"/>
     <animate attributeName="y" begin="0s;three.end+2s" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
              from="100" to="100"/>
     <set attributeName="opacity" to="1" begin="0s;three.end+2s" fill="freeze"/>
     <set attributeName="opacity" to="0" begin="three.end+1s"/>
   </image>
   
   <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-30-30-3.jpg" height="30" width="30" x="80" y="100"
          opacity="0">
     <animate id="two" attributeName="x" begin="one.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
              from="80" to="100"/>
     <animate attributeName="y" begin="one.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
              from="100" to="70"/>
     <set attributeName="opacity" to="1" begin="one.end" fill="freeze"/>
     <set attributeName="opacity" to="0" begin="three.end+1s"/>
   </image>

   <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-30-30-3.jpg" height="30" width="30" x="80" y="100"
          opacity="0">
     <animate id="three" attributeName="x" begin="two.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
              from="80" to="100"/>
     <animate attributeName="y" begin="two.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
              from="100" to="40"/>
     <set attributeName="opacity" to="1" begin="two.end" fill="freeze"/>
     <set attributeName="opacity" to="0" begin="three.end+1s"/>
   </image>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing: when those images move to the final position they pass another image. How can I make those moving images displayed on top of another image?

Comment: @rset_d Make sure the moving images are after the static image. SVG has painter's order. I.e. you paint on top of earlier stuff.